# Select records from table A not present table B

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables A and B with similar columns(user_id,phone_number,dateadded e.t.c). I want to retrieve distinct user_id and phonenumber from table A where phone_number starts with some prefixes and dateadded is between a given range, then return the result only if the user_id doesn't exist in table B.

Table A

```
memid  | phone_number | dateadded
   ----+--------------+------------------
   132   | 2337020013234| 2018-03-18 01:24:31
   22    | 2337060293922| 2018-02-18 03:55:02
   321   | 2337090294940| 2018-02-18 01:23:13
   3     | 2337030299931| 2018-06-18 12:00:01
   3     | 2337030299931| 2018-04-18 04:44:03
```

Table B

```
pid  | phone_number | dateadded
   ----+--------------+------------------
   132   | 2337020013234| 2018-07-14 03:34:24
   22    | 2337060293922| 2018-12-01 06:20:34
   321   | 2337090294940| 2018-10-06 07:24:54
   9     | 2337090993421| 2018-02-11 01:49:31
```

My Current Query

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT a.phonenum
FROM
  trxns a
  LEFT JOIN tickets b ON b.`pid`=a.`memid`
WHERE a.ttype = 'PCR' 
  AND a.dateadded BETWEEN '2018-01-18' 
  AND '2018-08-18' 
  AND (
    b.phonenum LIKE '233704%' 
    OR a.phonenum LIKE '233706%' 
    OR a.phonenum LIKE '233707%' 
    OR a.phonenum LIKE '233703%'
  )
  AND b.`pid` is NULL
```

I Expect to have distinct user_id with phone_number from table A that does not exist in table B. Please note that pid and memid columns both represent user id

Example Result below returns only phone_number of user 3 in table A because it matches (LIKE '233706%') and dateadded range (BETWEEN '2018-01-18' 
  AND '2018-08-18') and does not exist in table B

```
  phone_number
  ----+--------------
  2337030299931
```

Comment: This is what I expect: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What's the issue with your current query?

Comment: @JoshEller It returns this message: Lost connection to MySQL server during query.

Comment: Well, how are you running the query? That doesn't sound like an issue with the query itself.

Comment: I run the query in SQLYog against a remote MySQL DB, however the same happens when I run it on a local copy of the database too. Now i tried removing the last AND clause(AND b.`pid` is NULL) but it's only able to return 200 records, it loses connection when I increase the limit. I appreciate your audience

Comment: You need to update the question with your actual problem - which isn't the query. The query is fine. Show your error and give us more information. SOunds like you have a resource limitation. How many rows are in the two tables?

Comment: So the issue is that the query is taking too long and timing out, and you're really asking for performance help? If so, like Strawberry said, you're going to need to provide a lot more information. We can't possibly help with performance without knowing how big each table is, what the execution plan looks like, how many records you're expecting to be returned, how many records match each criteria, etc etc.

Comment: Thank you JoshEller and @strawberry. I have now updated the question. ianc I have over 100k records in table A and over 700k in table B.

Comment: I just don't get what's so difficult about 3 simple instructions :-(

Answer (score 0):

Apply all the conditions in the ON clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.phonenum
FROM trxns a LEFT JOIN tickets b 
ON 
  b.`pid`=a.`memid`
  AND a.ttype = 'PCR' 
  AND a.dateadded BETWEEN '2018-01-18' 
  AND '2018-08-18' 
  AND (
    b.phonenum LIKE '233704%' 
    OR a.phonenum LIKE '233706%' 
    OR a.phonenum LIKE '233707%' 
    OR a.phonenum LIKE '233703%'
  )
WHERE b.`pid` is NULL
```

But I think that the condition `b.phonenum LIKE '233704%'` is useless since you also apply `b.pid is NULL`

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

I was able to figure out what was wrong with the query above. It's more of a performance issue, Table A had over 100k records while table B had over 700k records. What I ought to have done is select distinct records from table B before performing a left join. Code below worked for me. Thanks.

```
SELECT 
      DISTINCT a.phonenum
    FROM
      trxns a
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(*) FROM table b GROUP BY pid) b ON b.`pid`=a.`memid`
    WHERE a.ttype = 'PCR' 
      AND a.dateadded BETWEEN '2018-01-18' 
      AND '2018-08-18' 
      AND (
        b.phonenum LIKE '233704%' 
        OR a.phonenum LIKE '233706%' 
        OR a.phonenum LIKE '233707%' 
        OR a.phonenum LIKE '233703%'
      )
      AND b.`pid` is NULL
```